# Is there any private api for iphone that detect sms sent or received

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-privateapi

I need to implement an app that detect an event when sms are received or sent on iPhone.Reading Sms is not required.

my app is going to run in background using apple's background multitasking feature for voip and navigators.

I can use private api as my client doesn't need this app on appstore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely possible to detect when an SMS has been received or sent without jailbreaking the device, but I believe you can only access the phone number of the SMS, and not the actual message text.

You need to link against the CoreTelephony private api, and then register an event observer with CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver. See http://tech.ruimaninfo.com/?p=83 for an example. I've confirmed this works on iOS4, 5 and 6.

Answer (score 1):

I have never did it myself, so I am not sure that it's possible.

However, if you are willing to go extra mile.

I would recommend you to look in couple of places (disassemble them and look how they work inside):

- /System/Library/Frameworks/PrivateFrameworks/ChatKit.framework
- /System/Libray/Messages/PlugIns/SMS.imservice
- /System/Library/BulletinBoardPlugins/SMSBBPlugin
- /System/Library/CoreServices/Springboard.app
- /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no any such type of API to getting sms sending/receiving notification on non-jail broken iPhone. Some of the services like Verizon providing API ,but such type of API is only working with Verizon network. On jail broken iPhone you can access internal SQLITE database.