# Detect incoming SMS with specific text in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, message, telephony

How to detect received SMS  and send  SMS to that number launching my app if this sms contain  specific message . Please suggest how i detect that a new messaqge received while my app is not running .

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933407/is-there-any-private-api-for-iphone-that-detect-sms-sent-or-received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is It is **NOT possible** in iOS device *(non jailbroken)* you cannot get any data on SMS messages or phone calls, so the best way is stop fighting with it. Not sure but it may achieve by jailbroken device.

> **Apple said -** In iPhone OS 4.0 and later, you can send text messages from within your application. This feature is strictly for sending messages. Incoming SMS messages go to the built-in Messages app.

Comment: you mean to say there is no way to detect that sms received

Comment: Exactly it is not possible in iOS device (non jailbroken).